# User-invisible tags in "django-taggit"

Tags: django, tags, django-taggit

I use to create tags - "django-taggit".
But there are several tags (20-30 pieces) that have a service value and should not appear in the template.
Is there an easy way to make them invisible to the user without messing with the database?

There are two opinions on this matter:

1. Add the "turn on-off" column to the database.
2. Try to somehow delete the desired tags by their "id".
   Is there a ready-made solution?

Answer (score 0):

I asked a question and the answer came by itself.
For this, there is a "content_type_id" column in the database or "Content type" in the admin panel.